# How to maintain the responsive layout by replacing marginTop in constraint-layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

From one view to next view vertically, marginTop is used but to get a responsive layout how to replace marginTop in constraint Layout android?

Comment: what do you mean by **responsive layout** here?

Comment: @JeelVankhede  i mean to say when i using a view below another view we use marginTop go maintain a distance. so it takes a fixed height between two views. but instead of marginTop what should i use so that it can take ratio or something that will change according to screen size.

Comment: You can use **guideline** for that purpose.